# using variables in $_post[]

Tags: php

I have been using variable in the name part of the input tag. Now while access answers as selected by users using $_post,It gives error as undefined index.Tell me how to get answers of all questions  as selected .

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
    $query=mysql_query("select q_detail,q_id from question where category=\"$value2\"",$connection);
    if(!$query)
    {
        echo mysql_error().'query failed';
    }
    $ans=1;
    while($value1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "Q-$i"."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo $value1['q_detail']."<br />";
        $i++;
        $qno=$value1['q_id'];
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from answer where ans_id=$qno");
        if(!$query1)
        {
            echo mysql_error().'query failed';
        }

        while($value2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $opt=$value2['option1'];
            $opt1=$value2['option2'];
            $opt2=$value2['option3'];
            $opt3=$value2['correct'];
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt\" name=\"$ans\">";
            echo "<span class=\"margin\">$opt</span>";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt1\" name=\"$ans\">";
            echo $opt1."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt2\" name=\"$ans\">";
            echo $opt2."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt3\" name=\"$ans\">";
            echo $opt3."&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />";
            $ans++;             
        }

    }
    echo"<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: Please use the search, you find it in the top-right corner of this website.

Comment: _"It gives error as undefined index"_ On what line?

Comment: Debugging steps: 1) Look at the generated HTML and check that it looks ok. 2) `print_r( $_POST )` to see that it contains what you need.

Comment: when i use $_post['$ans'] to access the option selected

Comment: Holy leaning toothpick syndrome, batman... Look up [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc)s. They'll make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the name of input as array, e.g.:

```
<input type="radio" value="Blah" name="answers[]" />
```

and in php code you can access this using the following code:

```
foreach($_POST['answers[]'] as $answer)
{
  echo $answer;
}
```

Comment: thanks...it works....but i am unable to accept your answer...3 min limitation something...

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the non-numeric value with single quotes.

```
$query=mysql_query("select q_detail,q_id 
                      from question where category='$value2'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $ans=1;

    if(isset($_POST))
    {
        echo $_POST['radio_' . $ans];
    }
    echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"\">";
    $query=mysql_query("select q_detail,q_id from question where category=\"$value2\"",$connection);
    if(!$query)
    {
        echo mysql_error().'query failed';
    }

    while($value1=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "Q-$i"."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo $value1['q_detail']."<br />";
        $i++;
        $qno=$value1['q_id'];
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from answer where ans_id=$qno");
        if(!$query1)
        {
            echo mysql_error().'query failed';
        }

        while($value2=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $opt=$value2['option1'];
            $opt1=$value2['option2'];
            $opt2=$value2['option3'];
            $opt3=$value2['correct'];
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt\" name=\"radio_$ans\">";
            echo "<span class=\"margin\">$opt</span>";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt1\" name=\"radio_$ans\">";
            echo $opt1."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt2\" name=\"radio_$ans\">";
            echo $opt2."&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type=\"radio\" value=\"$opt3\" name=\"radio_$ans\">";
            echo $opt3."&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />";
            $ans++;             
        }

    }
    echo"<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"submit\">";
    echo "</form>";
```

I've added the `if(isset($_POST))` and before the name I've added some text, because a name as a integer, can be used as a integer index in PHP. Array's can be called like

```
$ar = array("Name" => "VALUE");
echo $ar[0]; // Outputs VALUE
echo $ar["Name"]; // Outputs VALUE
```

Will both output "VALUE". So what you're trying to do. Is getting the value of index 1 instead of key 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $_POST['*actual radiobutton name*'], i. e. whatever the content of $ans is at the time of the echoing.

Answer (score 0):

You can also debug your form after submitting by using this code:

```
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($_POST); 
echo "</pre>";
```

This will show you the contents of the $_POST data so you can see if values are being passed correctly.

Comment: Might want to throw a call to `htmlentities()` in there for good measure.